# What is the substitute of REGEXP_INSTR (Redshift funtion) in SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

REGEXP_INSTR Function :
Searches a string for a regular expression pattern and returns an integer that indicates the beginning position or ending position of the matched substring. If no match is found, then the function returns 0.

Example :

```
    select email, regexp_instr(email,'@[^.]*') 
    from users 
    limit 5;
```

expected output:

```
email                                 | regexp_instr


Cum@accumsan.com                      |            4

lorem.ipsum@Vestibulumante.com        |           12

non.justo.Proin@ametconsectetuer.edu  |           16
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `locate` function

```
scala> df.show(true)
+--------------------+
|               email|
+--------------------+
|    Cum@accumsan.com|
|lorem.ipsum@Vesti...|
|non.justo.Proin@a...|
+--------------------+


scala> df.select(locate("@",'email)).show()
+-------------------+
|locate(@, email, 1)|
+-------------------+
|                  4|
|                 12|
|                 16|
+-------------------+
```